# How to check/test the output of a function without compiling the app in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

Let's say that I have a class in javascript with a method that takes a number and multiplies it by two:

```
class Foo {
  timesTwo(n) {
    return n * 2;
  }
...
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.timesTwo(2); // returns 4
```

What I'd normally do if I wanted to check the output would be to run `node foo.js` and see the output on my console.

Now I'm going to use a real life example in React, I'm trying to query something from my database (in this case firebase), It'll look something like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore';

class User {
  constructor() {
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    this.db = firebase.db();
  }

  getUsers() {
    // code that queries the db for
    // all users and returns them
  }
...
}

const user = new User();
user.(getUsers); // returns all users
```

If I wanted to quickly check the output of that method my original approach doesn't work (probably because this is more than just vanilla javascript), if I try to run `node user.js` a bunch of errors regarding the imports and ems modules appear.

My biggest delay while programming is having to test the output of something; waiting for the app to compile and then going to that specific screen (react & react-native) to see what the `console.log()` says. My question is: **is there any way I could get the output of a specific function / method without having to compile my entire app?**

I've tried solving the issues with the ems modules by importing the libraries by specific path with no luck. And I've checked some testing libraries, most of which specify that their main goal is to test user-related interactions and not functions or methods, but if there's any way that I could use one of these libraries to get the output of a method inside a class based component or a functional component without doing the steps I described above that'll save me incredible amounts of time. So far I haven't been able to find examples on how to do this with a testing library.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you are asking of us. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of the code you are trying to test as well as the test code.

Comment: You must provide a [example] as drew says. Without replicating your issue it is to difficult to determine your problem.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I'll try to update it, in short, what I'm looking for is a way to get the output of a react class method (or any other code snippet) in the console without having to navigate through my app and getting it manually with `console.log()`.

Comment: Wouldn't that just *be* a unit test? You say you want to test a react component, but you share plain JS classes, so it still isn't clear what & how you are trying to test. I'll wait for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the output is determined by a specific set of user interaction, it is tough to avoid doing it without compiling the entire app. Your suggested way of `console.log` right before the return method would work, otherwise places you can insert a `console.log` can be in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. This is an ES6 approach to testing things.

If the output is very easily replicable, and able to be encapsulated into an API instead of a client app interaction, I recommend you just do it as a regular NodeJS project preferably in your backend, especially when the logic is rather heavy and requires more testing. That would allow you to use your `node user.js` method on the command line. This is an ES5 approach to testing things.